# Background image for ::after and ::before pseudo elements that extend to the height of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div class="page">` centered at my page, and I'd like to have two background images running along the left and right edge of this element.

I've set up the `.page::before` and `.page::after` pseudo-elements and they seem to work great, but the background images repeat themselves up to the end of the visual viewport and not the whole page.

I've tried several things, playing with the `position:...` of the `div`, or setting `height: 100%` to `html` and/or `body` but to no avail.

I've made a [JsFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/uL6pe1f9/3/) to illustrate the problem. Ideally, I'd like not to mess with the html markup.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Including the markup and css here for future reference.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="page">__long content here__</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page {
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

.page::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(__some background image__);
    position: absolute;
    width: 94px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

.page::after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(__some background image__);
    position: absolute;
    width: 94px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 995px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positioning `.page` relatively [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/uL6pe1f9/4):

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Without it, the `height: 100%` on its pseudo-elements refers to the height of the viewport instead because they are absolutely-positioned.

Comment: So, when setting `position: absolute;` to an element it refers to its closest ancestor with `position: relative;`?

Comment: @lalibi: That is correct - otherwise it refers to the viewport.